# Qt tooltip brings window to front when it is being shown

Tags: c++, windows, qt

[Qt 5.4.2 on Windows 7] Create two windows (QDialog or QMainWindow) in same Qt app. Each of them have a tooltip associated. Position window d2 partially overlapping window d1. Mouse over d2 window and will see the tooltip "d2 window" pops up. The problem is that mouse hovering over d1 window will not only show tooltip "d1 window" but also moves window d1 to the front. Coming to the front is not the desired behaviour. Also clicking on d2 window client area will not move d2 to the foreground.  How can I not have the window come forward when displaying tooltip? I have already set WA_AlwaysShowToolTips and WA_ShowWithoutActivating flags.

*This problem does not seems to happen when there is only one qt window, but my design requires multiple windows.

```
QDialog * d1=new QDialog();
d1->setToolTip("d1 window");
d1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips);
d1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
d1->show();

QDialog * d2=new QDialog();
d2->setToolTip("d2 window");
d2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips);
d2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
d2->show();
```

Using spy++ shows that there are WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING window messages sent when tooltip is shown:
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0E14C740
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0E14C740
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0E14CA08

Answer (score 0):

This bug originally appeared in Qt 5.0, was reported in Qt 5.3.0 (QTBUG-39147), and fixed for 5.9.2 (on 7-19-2017). A removal of Qt_WS_* macros (replaced with Q_OS_* macros) and incomplete maintenance of the widgets/kerna/qtooltip.cpp module, caused the QTipLabel to be instantiated with the client widget as its parent widget. That had been a known problem on Windows which directly caused this dysfunction (Showing a tooltip raises the whole window).

See "Patch Set 6" in this Qt code review page, and it's associated "gitweb" link, and the original bug report:

- https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/177376/
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39147